# Google API Client linking wrong version of jackson-core

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-client

I am including the latest version of the Google API client (for interacting with AppEngine Endpoints).

I am getting this crash when assembling:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':backend:endpointsDiscoveryDocs'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:537)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:448)
  at com.google.api.server.spi.ObjectMapperUtil.createStandardObjectMapper(ObjectMapperUtil.java:75)
  at com.google.api.server.spi.ObjectMapperUtil.createStandardObjectMapper(ObjectMapperUtil.java:62)
  at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction.<clinit>(GenClientLibAction.java:37)
  at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.<init>(EndpointsTool.java:55)
  at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.server.task.GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.generateDiscoveryDocs(GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.java:122)
  at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
  at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
  ... 27 more
```

I checked my dependencies:

```
+--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev129-1.22.0
|    \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0
|         +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.1
|         |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.1
|         +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
```

As you can see, the version of `jackson-core` included is `2.1.3`.

However, the first declaration of the function `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z` occurs in version 2.3:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.java/

Are the Google libraries linking the wrong `jackson-core` version?

In case it is relevant, this is starting to happen during the process of migrating my v1 Google Cloud Endpoints code to v2.

## Update 1

The same error occurs when I remove the dependency from Google API Client or when I force upgrade it.

Example dependency tree when upgrading:

```
+--- com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev129-1.22.0
|    \--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0
|         +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0
|         |    |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.1
|         |    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9 -> 3.0.1
|         +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.22.0
|         |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.22.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3 -> 2.6.0
|         \--- com.google.guava:guava-jdk5:17.0
```

Gradle snippet I used to upgrade the dependency:

```
configurations {
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0'
            force 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind:jackson-databind:2.6.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle snippet I used to remove the dependency:

```
compile "com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v1-rev129-1.22.0", {
    exclude group: "com.fasterxml.jackson.core", module: "jackson-core"
}
```

## Update 2

It seems there might be an additional issue. When syncing there is the following error:

```
14:13:27.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.server.spi.tools.GenClientLibAction
14:13:27.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.api.server.spi.tools.EndpointsTool.<init>(EndpointsTool.java:55)
14:13:27.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at com.google.cloud.tools.gradle.endpoints.framework.server.task.GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.generateDiscoveryDocs(GenerateDiscoveryDocsTask.java:122)
14:13:27.882 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
```

It could be that this failed sync is making the builds fail each time.

Comment: did you figure out the GenClientLibAction? I'm having the same issue since migration

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am contemplating starting the system from scratch instead of migrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved through a hacky solution.

There is an issue on the [github issue tracker for the Google Cloud Platform](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/issues/52).

The [solution itself can be found here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/issues/52#issuecomment-335614311).

The fix, in short, is to move all buildscript dependencies into the root project `build.gradle` file.

> And the suggestion on that bug is to add all buildscript dependencies in the root. So just move everything from backend/build.gradle/buildscript -> build.gradle/buildscript, so that dependencies are forced to their latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

The Endpoints framework requires a newer version of Jackson than the client library does. If you have a client library and Endpoint framework in the same library, you should exclude the Jackson dependency from the client library.

Comment: I made an edit to my post with the results of what you suggest. I tried removing the dependency and forcibly upgrading it.

Comment: Long shot, but can you also try `exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'` in addition to what you have?

Comment: Unfortunately, no change (other than Guava not being a dependency anymore)